# Inverse quadratic optimization with linear equality constraints

Tags: quadratic-programming

considering following quadratic optimization problem with linear equality constraints
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\max_w~& r^\top w - \frac{1}{2}w^\top Q w \\
\mathrm{s.t.}& \sum w = 1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
By given $r\in\Re^{N\times 1}$ and positive definite $Q$, it is easy to find the analytical solution:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
-Q & \mathbf{1}_{N\times 1} \\ \mathbf{1}_{1\times N} & 0
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
w\\ \lambda
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
r\\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier. I was wondering, by given the optimal $w^*$, is it possible to derive the vector $r$?

I thought it would be easy, because
\begin{equation}
w = Q^{-1} (r + \mathbf{1}_{N\times 1} \lambda) \Longrightarrow \sum(w) = \mathbf{1}_{1\times N}Q^{-1} (r + \mathbf{1}_{N\times 1} \lambda) = 1
\end{equation}
hence
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
I_N & \mathbf{1}_{N\times 1} \\ \mathbf{1}_{1\times N}Q^{-1} & \mathbf{1}_{1\times N}Q^{-1}\mathbf{1}_{N\times 1}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
r\\ \lambda
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
Qw\\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
However, I found that matrix is not invertible due to rank deficiency. Can anyone help me to obtain the $r$ given $w^*$? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you pose is minimization of $||w-Q^{-1/2}r||_{Q^{1/2}}$ over the simplex, i.e. some weighted projection to the simplex. Given a projection $w^{*}$ there are generically infinitely many $r$ which yield the same projection (thus the issue with non-invertible). A picture in 2d says it all hopefully (here drawn for simple case with $W=I$, red line is the simplex, green line all possible $r$, two centers $r^{*}$ with corresponding level sets of the quadratic, and both of them yield the same projection $w^{*}$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Forming the Lagrangian

$$
L(w,\lambda) = r^{\top}w-\frac 12 w^{\top}Qw+\lambda(1^{\top}w-1)
$$

we have

$$
\nabla L = 0 = r^{\top}-w^{\top}Q+\lambda 1^{\top}=0
$$

multiplying by $w$ we have

$$
r^{\top}w-w^{\top}Qw+\lambda 1^{\top}w = 0\Rightarrow r^{\top}w-w^{\top}Qw+\lambda  = 0
$$

and finally

$$
r^{\top}-w^{\top}Q+(w^{\top}Qw-r^{\top}w) 1^{\top}=0
$$

or

$$
r - (w^{\top}r) 1 = Q^{\top}w-(w^{\top}Q^{\top}w)1\Rightarrow (I_n-W) r = Q^{\top}w-(w^{\top}Q^{\top}w)1
$$

then

$$
r = (I_n-W)^{-1}\left(Q^{\top}w-(w^{\top}Q^{\top}w)1\right)
$$

Here

$$
\cases{
1^{\top} = (1,\cdots,1)\\
I_n = \text{Identity matrix}\\
W = (w,\cdots,w)^{\top}
}
$$

Comment: $I_n - W$ will not be invertible, you are equivalent solving \begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
I_N & \mathbf{1}_{N\times 1} \\ w^\top & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
r\\ \lambda
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
Qw\\ w^\top Q w
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}, which is rank deficient

Comment: Invertibility depends on the **size** of $W$. If $\|w\| << 1$ is invertible for sure.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to verify your answer, because there is not inequality constraints, how can I ensure that abs(w) is much smaller than 1?

Comment: This is an extreme example. The identity matrix being dominant, $I_n-W$ will be invertible. Ill conditioning in the inversion may appear as the identity matrix is not dominant, but even in this case,$I_n- W$ may be numerically invertible.